# Visual Studio 2015 intellisense and ambiguous namespaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

The [Xamarin.Auth](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth) project broke up i.e. the source code was compiling OK and after another Xamarin.Android update it was suddenly broken.

It turned out that the problem arose after the `Mono.Android.dll` (Xamarin.Android) was extended by several namespace definitions.

I hunted the problem down to the following:

There is a dll #1 (Mono.Android.dll):

```
namespace Xamarin.Android
{
    public class Class1
    {
    }
}

namespace Android.OS
{
    public class Class2
    {
    }
}
```

There is a dll #2 (Xamarin.Auth.Android.dll):

```
namespace Xamarin.Auth
{
    //This does not compile. See the problem description below.
    public class User1 : Android.OS.Class2
    {
    }
}
```

Intellisense shows the following problem:

> > Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'OS' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Android' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

This can be fixed by changing the latter namespace to something else or by using the `global::` identifier:

```
namespace SomeOtherNamespace
{
    //This compiles ok.
    public class User1 : Android.OS.Class2
    {
    }
}

namespace Xamarin.Auth
{
    //This compiles ok.
    public class User1 : global::Android.OS.Class2
    {
    }
}
```

The question is: why does not intellisense give a warning that the `Android` namespace branch is ambiguous between `global::Xamarin.Android` and `global::Android`? What is the good way out of it? Always use `global::` namespace identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `global` directive to tell the compiler it should evaluate the namespace from the root, else it tries to evaluate the namespace relative from the current namespace. Using `global` always uses the full qualified namespace name, so that is why it works when you prefix it.

Another option would be using an alias:

```
using AOS = Android.OS;

namespace Xamarin
{
    public class User1 : AOS.Class2
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Did not I clearly showed this workaround myself in the question?

Comment: Sorry. I missed that. Updated.

Comment: Thanks for the alias idea, I will consider that. Is there a way to make Visual Studio always insert `global::` when automating namespace provision inline?

Comment: Not that I am aware off. Sorry. You could alias the assembly, then you only need to use the directive of the assembly when you use it.